# Django MAKEMESSAGES ignores LOCALE_PATHS

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization

I am running Django 1.9

If I use the default LOCALE folder everything works.
If I rename the LOCALE folder to MY_LOCALE and

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my_locale'),
)
```

The strings are loading correctly when I run `./manage.py runserver`

BUT if I run

```
django-admin makemessages -l en
```

I am getting

```
CommandError: Unable to find a locale path to 
store translations for file _templates/account/login.html
```

The folder exist but it is looking for LOCALE not for MY_LOCALE

Any Ideas ?

Comment: folder name is in capital letters?

Comment: No, it is not. Folder name is exactly how it is difined in LOCALE_PATHS